# Do you need a solid understanding of Swing in order to move on to JavaFX?

Tags: swing, javafx-2

My Goal is to use Swing with JavaFX, since I am completely new to both I figured why not now. I am creating a WhiteBoard application ultimately, but in my first pass I am just making an app called StickyNotes only in Swing.

But I also want all the new features of JavaFX too.

I have been working with Swing for a couple of weeks and have quite a bit accomplished so far.

So would now be a good time to start using JavaFX?

P.S. This must be the link I saw previously: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm

Comment: *"My Goal is to use Swing with JavaFX, since I am completely new to both I figured why not now."* If you want to make your life easier, use one or the other. Mixing them is doable but (somewhat) painful.

Comment: @assylias Oh I see. I was just sitting here reading some JavaFX pages and it does look like it has it's own layouts, pane system etc. Hmm, well the basic skills I picked up in Swing can only help if it turns out JavaFX is better than Swing.

Comment: And to answer the question in your title: no, some parts are similar (GUI thread, observer pattern...) some are quite different (layout construction, data binding...).

Comment: Yes thats right. I edited the tag in op to include javafx-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX will eventually replace Swing and most, if not all, new development at Oracle will directed towards JavaFX. If you are new to both, I see no advantage to learning Swing - just start working in JavaFX as they have different event models.

As a quick way to produce a new GUI app., try out the JavaFX SceneBuilder: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm

It's an excellent tool, and allows you to produce a fully functional application in very little time. Here are a couple other JavaFX links that I've found useful:

http://fxexperience.com/

http://www.learnjavafx.typepad.com/weblog/

Comment: The two links above should be: [fxexperience.com](http://fxexperience.com/) and [learnjavafx](http://www.learnjavafx.typepad.com/weblog/)

Comment: Thanks a million, did not know this going in... thanks for the great answer.